# Retrieving Data from MySQL in batches via Python

Tags: python, mysql

I would like to make this process in batches, because of the volume.

Here's my code:

```
 getconn = conexiones()
 con = getconn.mysqlDWconnect()
 with con:
     cur = con.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
     cur.execute("SELECT id, date, product_id, sales FROM sales")
     rows = cur.fetchall()
```

How can I implement an index to fetch the data in batches?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73092346/5983841

Answer (score 44, accepted):

First point: a python `db-api.cursor` is an iterator, so unless you really **need** to load a whole batch in memory at once, you can just start with using this feature, ie instead of:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
   do_something_with(row)
```

you could just:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable")
for row in cursor:
   do_something_with(row)
```

Then if your db connector's implementation still doesn't make proper use of this feature, it will be time to add LIMIT and OFFSET to the mix:

```
# py2 / py3 compat
try:
    # xrange is defined in py2 only
    xrange
except NameError:
    # py3 range is actually p2 xrange
    xrange = range

cursor.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM mytable")
count = cursor.fetchone()[0]
batch_size = 42 # whatever

for offset in xrange(0, count, batch_size):
    cursor.execute(
        "SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT %s OFFSET %s", 
        (batch_size, offset))
   for row in cursor:
       do_something_with(row)
```

Comment: Your solution is so much cleaner than mine!

Comment: Just to make a note for everyone reviewing this "xrange" has been depreciated in Python 3.

Comment: How to expand this solution to write batch_size number of rows from each iteration to csv file? For example in each iteration to write 1000 rows till the end of the count?

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
SELECT id, date, product_id, sales FROM sales LIMIT X OFFSET Y;
```

where X is the size of the batch you need and Y is current offset (X times number of current iterations for example)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on akalikin's answer, you can use a stepped iteration to split the query into chunks, and then use LIMIT and OFFSET to execute the query.

```
cur = con.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sales")

for i in range(0,cur.fetchall(),5):
    cur2 = con.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cur2.execute("SELECT id, date, product_id, sales FROM sales LIMIT %s OFFSET %s" %(5,i))
    rows = cur2.fetchall()
    print rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, here's how I implement it with your suggestions:

```
control = True
index = 0
while control==True:
   getconn = conexiones()
   con = getconn.mysqlDWconnect()
   with con:
        cur = con.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        query = "SELECT id, date, product_id, sales FROM sales  limit 10 OFFSET " + str(10 * (index))
        cur.execute(query)
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        index = index+1        
        if len(rows)== 0:
            control=False
   for row in rows:
        dataset.append(row)
```

Comment: I see you're collecting rows in what seems to be a `list` or `list`-like `dataset` object, which kind of defeat the whole point of batching and direct cursor iteration, ie avoiding to load the whole shebang in memory... May I ask how you're using this `dataset` object ? There might be a much better solution here, Python has a strong support for lazy evaluation.

Comment: I need to retrieve 18M rows dataset, after it I have to clean some references that I'm not interested (subset) and merge it with other one.

Comment: And do you really need to get the whole dataset in memory to do so ??? When working on "huge" datasets, the canonical pattern is to use a "stream/process/write" solution.

Comment: I have been thinking on it... I would try to implement a loop trying to lighten the process. Thank you so much for your advice. :)

Comment: You may want to have a look at generator functions - they are a great way to provide lazy evaluation at very little cost.

Comment: I have similar problem where I want to fetch 15m rows...
I wonder what solution you implemented...Can I use the above which bruno suggested? or how do I implement this "generator" function along with the above to fetch in batches of say 5000 rows at a time...I am sort of reasonably new to python so have not used this generator approach!
your help will be much appreciated...thanks