# pymysql retrievingdata in batches

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

i am using pymysql to interact with an sql db, here is the code:

```
    query = "SELECT * FROM my_table"
    c = db.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    c.execute(query)
    c.fetchall()
```

now i am doing this for a database of 3000 enteries which isn't alot, i plan to use this on a database with 15 million enteries and i want to take the data out in a loop as batches of 5000 enteries

i wonder if i need to do this using LIMIT and OFFSET in my query, or can i just do it using a method in the pymysql module... Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving Data from MySQL in batches via Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32625593/retrieving-data-from-mysql-in-batches-via-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use `limit` or `offset`.

For `pymysql`, all you need is [`pymysql.cursors.SSCursor`](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.SSCursor). With this cursor, the program will not load all data in memory first before you can process rows and write rows to disk.

Sample code:

(mysql credentials and `import`s are omitted)

```
TEST_ROW_SIZE = 200000
connection = pymysql.connect(**config,  cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.SSCursor)

with connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = f"select * from {table}"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        n = 0
        with open('./pymysql-1row-write.csv', 'w') as out:
            csv_out = csv.writer(out)
            for row in cursor:
                # print(row)
                # do something with the row
                csv_out.writerow(row)
                n += 1
                if n % 10000 == 0:
                    print(f"{n} rows dumped")
                if n % TEST_ROW_SIZE == 0:
                    print("Test Done!")
                    exit(1)
```

Use `fetchmany`

```
TEST_ROW_SIZE = 200000
FETACH_ROW_SIZE = 10000
connection = pymysql.connect(**config,  cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.SSCursor)

with connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = f"select * from {table}"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        n = 0
        with open('./pymysql-fetchmany-write.csv', 'w') as out:
            csv_out = csv.writer(out)
            result = cursor.fetchmany(FETACH_ROW_SIZE)
            while result:
                # do something with fetched rows
                csv_out.writerows(result)
                result_len = len(result)
                print(f"{result_len} rows dumped")
                n += result_len
                result = cursor.fetchmany(FETACH_ROW_SIZE)
                if n % TEST_ROW_SIZE == 0:
                    print("Test Done!")
                    exit(2)

            print("No data")
            exit(1)
```

---

If you are using Mysql's official python connector [`mysql-connector-python`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python), by default it is "unbuffered".

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
# try the buffered one and see what happens :)
# cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)


sql = f"select * from {table}"
cursor.execute(sql)
n = 0
with open('./data-mysql-connector.csv', 'w') as out:
# with open('./data-mysql-connector-buffered.csv', 'w') as out:
    csv_out = csv.writer(out)
    for row in cursor:
        # print(row)
        # do something with the row
        csv_out.writerow(row)
        n += 1
        if n % 10000 == 0:
            print(f"{n} rows dumped")
```

---

[`mysqlclient`](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python) also has a [`SSCursor`](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html#cursor-objects) but I didn't try this connector.

> `SSCursor`
>
> A “server-side” cursor. Like Cursor but uses
> CursorUseResultMixIn. Use only if you are dealing with potentially
> large result sets

Answer (score -1):

the way i'm doing this is, is like this:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM my_table"
c = db.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
c.execute(query)

limit = 5000
not_done = True

while not_done:
    data = []
    for _ in range(limit):
        try:
            data += [c.fetchone()]
        except:
            not_done = False
            break
    do_something_with_data()
```